# "Files" File Manager opening but not loading the directory

Tags: filemanager

When i start files through the UI, it starts but it doesn't load the directory, no error message, just infinite loading. But the file upload tool does work. The bar on the left is still there, but the actual contents isn't loading. I do have multiple mods installed but i have been using them for a long time and they never really impacted anything. I also tried using nautilis in the command line.

Mods : Application Menu, Blur My Shell, Caffeine, Dash to dock, Date Menu Formatter, Desktop Clock, Open Wheater.
Picture: https://imgur.com/a/pYu4aS3

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting .

Comment: Try to stop and restart Nautilus: `nautilus -q` followed by `nautilus &`.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** In order to better diagnose your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Also, when you run `nautilus` from command line, do you see any warnings/errors? If so, please post in your question. Thanks